# deferred prepare could not be completed, 3 SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I have 3 SQL Servers, and I'm getting strange behavior with OpenRowset.

Given:

- Server 1 = 192.168.1.1,
- Server 2 = 192.168.1.2,
- Server 3 = 192.168.1.3,
- Server 4 = 192.168.1.4

SQL:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 
                'Data Source=192.168.1.1;Persist Security 
Info=True;uid=sa;pwd=password',  
                'SELECT * FROM  dfs_database.dbo.dfs_vehicledata ') AS a;
```

Here is the strange part: if I run the above SQL statement on servers .3 and .4, everything works fine.

However, if I run the SQL statement on server .2, I get:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".
>
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Invalid object name 'dfs_database.dbo.dfs_vehicledata'.

So what could make one relationship not work when the others work fine? Any ideas? They are all SQL Server express, and all report having SQLNCLI11 providers.

Comment: Your error message says `Invalid object name 'dfs_database.dbo.dfs_vehicledata'`. Are you sure you are hitting the right DB? The table name may be case sensitive through open query, too.

Comment: Can you run same query on that server locally?

Comment: Try to setup a linked server that maps to that server and check if you can access any object there.

Comment: I'm accessing the same computer from 3 places.  it works in 2, so the object reference must be right.

Also I can run it locally from server .1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `OpenRowSet` it look like this:

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
'Server=ipHere\ExtentionNameifHas;Database=DBName;Uid=userName;PWD=Password;'
,'SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT * FROM  
dfs_database.dbo.dfs_vehicledata'
```

Comment: Thanks, you got the fix.  It turns out that replacing
    Data Source=192.168.1.1
With
    Server=25.100.85.28;Database=DFS_DATABASE
did the trick, even when the provider is left as "SQLOLEDB"          Now why only  the one computer needed that adjusted is curious.

Answer (score 0):

From the error log try changing the OLE DB provider name from 'SQLOLEDB' to 'SQLNCLI11' and also
check the location of the object. Make sure to give the full location with database, table etc.